# Unicode URLs shown in wrong order

Tags: url, unicode

I have enabled unicode urls in my joomla site

My language is Persian which is a right-to-left language but
 urls written in persian appear in wrong order. For example:

Mysite.com/محصولات/محصول-اول

It translates to:

Mysite.com/first-product/products

Which should have been:

Mysite.com/products/first-product

This is only a matter of displaying text. I know that the actual text the server receives is in correct order because url-encoded version has the correct order.

(If you don't get the idea type "something.com/" in your url bar. Now copy/paste this at the end of url

محصولات

Now type a slash and copy/paste this at the end

محصول

You see? The last one should have gone to the right but goes to the left)

I have two questions regarding this issue:

1-is there anything i can do to display urls in correct order?

2-can it affect how google indexes my pages? Can it misdirect google?

Comment: This is about the use of browsers, not programming. The issue seems to be that browsers render the URL in the address bar with due consideration of the directionality of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of the url display is totally correct in Unicode sense, as the slash is defined as bidirectionally neutral:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002f/index.htm

Thus, standing between two arabic (right-to-left) words, the slash has to adapt to the writing direction of the surrounding words. The slash would, though, never adapt to the writing direction of the whole line within in a right-to-left neighborhood.

To answer your questions:

(1) It is not possible to influence this behaviour if you do not change the URL, as Jukka K. Korpela already assumed.

(2) As long as the order of the words is correctly encoded, I do not see any bad consequences for search engine indexings.

If you want to change it anyway, and assumed that your URLs are artificial and do no represent real paths, I can see the following workarounds:

(a) Substitute the slash with another "strong" symbol which influences the writing direction.

(b) Insert a "pseudo strong" character before (U+200e) the slash, which will enforce LTR for the slash.

Hope this helps.